# How to create your own package for interaction with word, pdf etc

Tags: pdf, package

I know that there are a lot of packages around which allow you to create or read e.g. PDF, Word and other files.

What I'm interested in (and never learned at the university) is how you create such a package? Are you always relying on source code being given by the original company (such as Adobe or Microsoft), or is there another clever way of working around it? Should I analyze the individual bytes I see in e.g. PDF files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies.

Some companies provide an SDK ("Software Development Kit") for their own data format, others only a specification (i.e., [Adobe for PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), [Microsoft for Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and it's up to the software developer to make sure to write a correct implementation.

Since that can be a lot of work – the PDF specification, for example, runs to over 700 pages and doesn't go deep into practically *required* material such as LZW, JPEG/JPEG2000, color theory, and math transformations – and you need a *huge* set of data to test against, it's way easier to use the work that others have done on it.

If you are interested in writing a support library for a certain file format which

1. is not legally protected,
2. has **no**, or only sparse (official) documentation,
3. and is not already under deconstruction elsewhere,<sup>a</sup>

then yes: you need to

1. gather as many possible different files;
2. from as many possible sources;
   (ideally, you should have at least one program that can both read and create the files)
3. inspect them on the byte level;
4. create a 'reader' which works on *all* of the test files;
5. if possible, interesting, and/or required, create a 'writer' that can create a new file in that format from scratch or can convert data in another format to this one.

There is 'cleverness' involved, mainly in #3, as you need to be very well versed in how data representation works in general. You should be able to tell code from data, and string data from floating point, and UTF8 encoded strings from MacRoman-encoded strings (and so on).

I've done this a couple of times, primarily to inspect the data of various games, mainly because it's huge fun! (Fair warning: it can also be incredibly frustrating.) See Reverse Engineering's [Reverse engineering file containing sprites](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8105/2959) for an example approach; notably, at the bottom of my answer in there I admit defeat and start using the phrases "possibly" and "may" and "probably", which is an indication I did not get any further on that.

---

<sup>a</sup> Not necessarily of course. You can cooperate with other whose expertise lies elsewhere, or even do "grunt work" for existing projects – finding out and codifying fairly trivial subcases.

There are also advantages of working independently on existing projects. For example, with the experience of my own PDF reader (written from scratch), I was able to point out a [bug in PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21702776/2564301).

Comment: Great thanks for your answer! I guess PDF is a bit too complicated for me, I'll start with bmp :)